# Does it matter if I use .\ in my Journal field in the bib file?

Tags: bibtex, achemso

When using bibtex and citing a paper should I use

```
journal = {J. Am.\ Chem.\ Soc.},
```

or is

```
journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
```

OK? I know in body text when you have a period that isn't after a single letter you are supposed to mark it as not a sentence ending space (So Ph. D. doesn't have a huge space in the middle of it, for example), but does that have any effect in journal titles in the citations? I've been taking the time to fix it, but it takes a while (even with find and replace), and I can't really see any difference, so I wanted to double check this did something.

Comment: You've forgotten the tie between `J.` and `Am.` ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright I thought LaTeX automatically didn't put sentence spaces after periods that follow a single letter? (So J. Wright, but Dr.\ Wright?)

Comment: I'm not worrying about spacing, I'm worrying about line breaking. Do you really want `J.` at the end of a line?

Comment: @JosephWright Ah. So I should not have removed all the .\ after David's answer.

Comment: @JosephWright Oh so even in Acta Cryst. I should tie Acta and Cryst even though there is no . after Acta.

Comment: No, as 'Acta' is a longer word. It's normal to tie single-letter abbreviations for the same reason Knuth recommends a tie when handling single-letter variable names: they look poor at the end of lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`article` class (and probably most others) defines the bibliography with

```
     \sfcode`\.\@m
```

so you do not get end of sentence spaces.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `\sfcode` short for?

Comment: Time for s:.\ :. :g (Well, a notepad++ find and replace doing the same thing since I'm on windows, but you get the idea)

Comment: this is equivalent to `\frenchspacing` -- every space has equal width, none of this "wider space after sentence-ending periods".

Comment: @SeanAllred space factor the amount over 1000 that space is stretched so `\@m` = 1000/1000 = 1.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well not quite same as frenchspacing, space after `;` etc still stretch.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- that's certainly peculiar.  i don't think i've ever seen a semicolon in a bibliography *except* in a title, and that's really the wrong place to have an extra-wide space.  stretched spaces should best occur at "logical" breaks -- between author(s) and title, between title and publication info, etc.  if it weren't for the way most bibliographic processors wipe out such useful information, a more constrained approach could be applied.  (of course, there's always ragged right.)

Comment: @SeanAllred `sf` is for _space factor_.